# Parse HTML bookmarks file to JSON using python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, parsing

I am currently working on a project for an online course, my goal is to create a bookmark manager web app. So I created this python script to parse a chrome/firefox HTML bookmarks file (Netscape-Bookmark-file) into a JSON object, while preserving the hierarchy and location of the folders and urls.

The code works fine and parses the HTML file to JSON correctly.

I feel like the code is messy and that the approach I am using is not the best. I would appreciate any critique/criticism in any aspect of the code.

The code runs by passing the html file location to the `main()` function:

```py
output = main("html_file_location")
```

Here is the Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Counter for the id of each item (folders and urls)
ID = 1


def indexer(item, index):
    """
    Add position index for urls and folders
    """
    if item.get("type") in ["url", "folder"]:
        item["index"] = index
        index += 1
    return index


def parse_url(child, parent_id):
    """
    Function that parses a url tag <DT><A>
    """
    global ID
    result = {
        "type": "url",
        "id": ID,
        "index": None,
        "parent_id": parent_id,
        "url": child.get("href"),
        "title": child.text,
        "date_added": child.get("add_date"),
        "icon": child.get("icon"),
    }
    # getting icon_uri & tags are only applicable in Firefox
    icon_uri = child.get("icon_uri")
    if icon_uri:
        result["icon_uri"] = icon_uri
    tags = child.get("tags")
    if tags:
        result["tags"] = tags.split(",")
    ID += 1
    return result


def parse_folder(child, parent_id):
    """
    Function that parses a folder tag <DT><H3>
    """
    global ID
    result = {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": ID,
        "index": None,
        "parent_id": parent_id,
        "title": child.text,
        "date_added": child.get("add_date"),
        "date_modified": child.get("last_modified"),
        "special": None,
        "children": [],
    }
    # for Bookmarks Toolbar in Firefox and Bookmarks bar in Chrome
    if child.get("personal_toolbar_folder"):
        result["special"] = "toolbar"
    # for Other Bookmarks in Firefox
    if child.get("unfiled_bookmarks_folder"):
        result["special"] = "other_bookmarks"
    ID += 1
    return result


def recursive_parse(node, parent_id):
    """
    Function that recursively parses folders and lists <DL><p>
    """
    index = 0
    # case were node is a folder
    if node.name == "dt":
        folder = parse_folder(node.contents[0], parent_id)
        items = recursive_parse(node.contents[2], folder["id"])
        folder["children"] = items
        return folder
    # case were node is a list
    elif node.name == "dl":
        data = []
        for child in node:
            tag = child.contents[0].name
            if tag == "h3":
                folder = recursive_parse(child, parent_id)
                index = indexer(folder, index)
                data.append(folder)
            elif tag == "a":
                url = parse_url(child.contents[0], parent_id)
                index = indexer(url, index)
                data.append(url)
        return data


def parse_root_firefox(root):
    """
    Function to parse the root of the firefox bookmark tree
    """
    # create bookmark menu folder and give it an ID
    global ID
    bookmarks = {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": ID,
        "index": 0,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "title": "Bookmarks Menu",
        "date_added": None,
        "date_modified": None,
        "special": "main",
        "children": [],
    }
    ID += 1
    index = 0  # index for bookmarks/bookmarks menu
    main_index = 1  # index for root level
    result = [0]  # root contents
    for node in root:
        # skip node if not <DT>
        if node.name != "dt":
            continue
        # get tag of first node child
        tag = node.contents[0].name
        if tag == "a":
            url = parse_url(node.contents[0], 1)
            index = indexer(node, index)
            bookmarks["children"].append(url)
        if tag == "h3":
            folder = recursive_parse(node, 1)
            # check for special folders (Other Bookmarks / Toolbar)
            # add them to root level instead of inside bookmarks
            if folder["special"]:
                folder["parent_id"] = 0
                main_index = indexer(folder, main_index)
                result.append(folder)
            else:
                index = indexer(folder, index)
                bookmarks["children"].append(folder)

    result[0] = bookmarks
    return result


def parse_root_chrome(root):
    """
    Function to parse the root of the chrome bookmark tree
    """
    global ID
    # Create "other bookmarks" folder and give it an ID
    other_bookmarks = {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": ID,
        "index": 1,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "title": "Other Bookmarks",
        "date_added": None,
        "date_modified": None,
        "special": "other_bookmarks",
        "children": [],
    }
    ID += 1
    result = [0]
    index = 0
    for node in root:
        if node.name != "dt":
            continue
        # get the first child element (<H3> or <A>)
        element = node.contents[0]
        tag = element.name
        # if an url tag is found at root level, add it to "Other Bookmarks" children
        if tag == "a":
            url = parse_url(node.contents[0], 1)
            index = indexer(node, index)
            other_bookmarks["children"].append(url)
        elif tag == "h3":
            # if a folder tag is found at root level, check if its the main "Bookmarks Bar", else append to "Other Bookmarks" children
            if element.get("personal_toolbar_folder"):
                folder = recursive_parse(node, 0)
                folder["index"] = 0
                folder["special"] = "main"
                result[0] = folder
            else:
                parent_id = other_bookmarks["id"]
                folder = recursive_parse(node, parent_id)
                index = indexer(folder, index)
                other_bookmarks["children"].append(folder)
    # add "Other Bookmarks" folder to root if it has children
    if len(other_bookmarks["children"]) > 0:
        result.append(other_bookmarks)
    return result


# Main function
def main(bookmarks_file):
    """
    Main function, takes in a HTML bookmarks file from Chrome/Firefox and returns a JSON nested tree of the bookmarks.
    """
    # Open HTML Bookmark file and pass contents into beautifulsoup
    with open(bookmarks_file, encoding="Utf-8") as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(markup=f, features="html5lib", from_encoding="Utf-8")
    # Check if HTML Bookmark version is Chrome or Firefox
    # Prepare the data to be parsed
    # Parse the root of the bookmarks tree
    heading = soup.find("h1")
    root = soup.find("dl")
    if heading.text == "Bookmarks":
        bookmarks = parse_root_chrome(root)
    elif heading.text == "Bookmarks Menu":
        bookmarks = parse_root_firefox(root)
    return bookmarks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Global state

This:

```
# Counter for the id of each item (folders and urls)
ID = 1
```

has issues. It will prevent your code from being re-entrant. Instead, this should either be passed around in your function parameters, or made a member of a class.

### Type hints

```
def indexer(item, index):
```

could stand to get some type hints. Probably `index: int`, return value is `-> int`, and `item` is a `: dict`. However,

1. You're better off using `Dict[str, ???]` - I don't know what the values are; and
2. You're even better off representing the item not as a dictionary, but as a more strongly-typed class instance - maybe a `@dataclass`, or at least a named tuple - to gain confidence that your data are valid and your code is correct.

### Enums

Another aspect of strengthening your types is to reframe this:

```
item.get("type") in ["url", "folder"]:
```

as an `Enum`. Also, you shouldn't `in`-compare to a list; do it to a `set` literal instead, i.e. `{'url', 'folder'}`. This will work equally well for strings or enums.

### Generators

Consider replacing this:

```
    data = []
    for child in node:
        data.append(folder)
    return data
```

with

```
for child in node:
    yield folder
```

It's easier to write, and will use up less memory - though the last bit will only matter if you're processing millions of these.

### Returns from main

```
def main(bookmarks_file):
    return bookmarks
```

This means that your `main` isn't really a `main`; something else (that you unfortunately haven't shown) is calling it. This method needs to be renamed, and your *actual* `main` needs to call it.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, there were quite somethings I didn't know about that I have learned. I do have some questions tho.
1. from my experience it seems that passing ``ID`` through 3 or 4 functions will cause the code to be quite difficult to maintain. (I guess changing to a class will be better?)
2. Wouldn't using Enum just to increment a dictionary value be over-complicating the code?
3. You mentioned using the Generator for returning the values, but since I am creating a nested structure, I will have to add them to a list after each yield anyway. won't that make it usless?

Comment: _passing ID through 3 or 4 functions will cause the code to be quite difficult to maintain_ - Your thinking on this may evolve as you mature as a programmer. Ease of maintenance overlaps with ease of testability, and having functions that rely on their parameters only and have no side effects really enhances testability.

Comment: _Wouldn't using Enum just to increment a dictionary value be over-complicating the code_ - It may very well end up producing code that is longer, but it will also be code that is inherently resistant to certain classes of errors where the data are not checked for validity until it's too late.

Comment: _since I am creating a nested structure, I will have to add them to a list after each yield anyway_ - Nested generators are entirely possible.